# Read session cookie name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am new in asp.net core and set cookie name in `Startup.cs` using below code:

```
services.AddSession(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "xxxxxxxx";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
});
```

I want to read above cookie name in a controller. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the cookie name in the `appsettings.json`, then, use the [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to get the cookie name in the Startup.cs and Controller.

Code like this:

appsettings.json:

```
{ 
  "SessionCookie": "SessionCookie001"
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {  
        ...
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = Configuration["SessionCookie"];
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddRouting(options =>
        {
            options.ConstraintMap.Add("customName", typeof(MyCustomConstraint));
        });
    }
```

Code in the Controller:

```
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context; 
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ApplicationDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
        _hostingEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {  
        var sessioncookiename = Configuration["SessionCookie"];

        return View();
    }
```

Besides, you could also use [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=net-5.0) class to read the appsettings.json, and then deserialize the json string to a dictionary, then get the cookie name. For example, use the following code in the controller action method:

```
        var jsonFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.json");
        string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
        Dictionary<string, object> json_Dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

        var sessionname = json_Dictionary["SessionCookie"];
```

The result like this:

[image]